# signalR group notification + Design pattern

Tags: signalr

I have an app which ties members to their respective groups the moment they complete registeration. e.g Payroll staffs --> Payroll group, Helpdesk staffs --> Helpdesk group. I want to make use of signalR to cater for their notification requirements so whenever Payroll staffs does something significant that requires to notify the rest, it publishes a message and only those inside the Payroll group will receive the notification.

A staff is **not restricted** to only one group but unlimited no. of groups depending on the company requirements.

I am not exactly sure how to go about this but what I can think of is when the moment a staff signs in, my app gets data from the db, maybe a string of concatened groups and does a loop to 'subscribes' to all the groups they belong to and after that store that group infomation data from the db in a session variable and use it as a subscription list everytime the user changes page so that they can receive notifications throughout their session on the app.

Anyone has got any suggestion to handle my situation better? Thanks.